# Formatting into CSV JSON file using jq

Tags: arrays, json, formatting, jq

I've some data in a file called myfile.json. I need to format using jq - in JSON it looks like this ;

`{
  "result": [
    {
      "service": "ebsvolume",
      "name": "gtest",
      "resourceIdentifier": "vol-999999999999",
      "accountName": "g-test-acct",
      "vendorAccountId": "12345678912",
      "availabilityZone": "ap-southeast-2c",
      "region": "ap-southeast-2",
      "effectiveHourly": 998.56,
      "totalSpend": 167.7,
      "idle": 0,
      "lastSeen": "2018-08-16T22:00:00Z",
      "volumeType": "io1",
      "state": "in-use",
      "volumeSize": 180,
      "iops": 2000,
      "throughput": 500,
      "lastAttachedTime": "2018-08-08T22:00:00Z",
      "lastAttachedId": "i-086f957ee",
      "recommendations": [
        {
          "action": "Rightsize",
          "preferenceOrder": 2,
          "risk": 0,
          "savingsPct": 91,
          "savings": 189.05,
          "volumeType": "gp2",
          "volumeSize": 120,
        },
        {
          "action": "Rightsize",
          "preferenceOrder": 4,
          "risk": 0,
          "savingsPct": 97,
          "savings": 166.23,
          "volumeType": "gp2",
          "volumeSize": 167,
        },
        {
          "action": "Rightsize",
          "preferenceOrder": 6,
          "risk": 0,
          "savingsPct": 91,
          "savings": 111.77,
          "volumeType": "gp2",
          "volumeSize": 169,
        }
      ]
    }
}`

I have it formatted better with the following

`jq '.result[] | [.service,.name,.resourceIdentifier,.accountName,.vendorAccountId,.availabilityZone,.region,.effectiveHourly,.totalSpend,.idle,.lastSeen,.volumeType,.state,.volumeSize,.iops,.throughput,.lastAttachedTime,.lastAttachedId] |@csv' ./myfile.json`

This nets the following output ;

`"\"ebsvolume\",\"gtest\",\"vol-999999999999\",\"g-test-acct\",\"12345678912\",\"ap-southeast-2c\",\"ap-southeast-2\",998.56,167.7,0,\"2018-08-16T22:00:00Z\",\"io1\",\"in-use\",180,2000,500,\"2018-08-08T22:00:00Z\",\"i-086f957ee\""`

I figured out this but its not exactly what I am trying to achieve. I want to have each recommendation listed underneath on a seperate line, and not at the end of the same line.

`jq '.result[] | [.service,.name,.resourceIdentifier,.accountName,.vendorAccountId,.availabilityZone,.region,.effectiveHourly,.totalSpend,.idle,.lastSeen,.volumeType,.state,.volumeSize,.iops,.throughput,.lastAttachedTime,.lastAttachedId,.recommendations[].action] |@csv' ./myfile.json`

This nets :

`"\"ebsvolume\",\"gtest\",\"vol-999999999999\",\"g-test-acct\",\"12345678912\",\"ap-southeast-2c\",\"ap-southeast-2\",998.56,167.7,0,\"2018-08-16T22:00:00Z\",\"io1\",\"in-use\",180,2000,500,\"2018-08-08T22:00:00Z\",\"i-086f957ee\",\"Rightsize\",\"Rightsize\",\"Rightsize\""`

What I want is

`"\"ebsvolume\",\"gtest\",\"vol-999999999999\",\"g-test-acct\",\"12345678912\",\"ap-southeast-2c\",\"ap-southeast-2\",998.56,167.7,0,\"2018-08-16T22:00:00Z\",\"io1\",\"in-use\",180,2000,500,\"2018-08-08T22:00:00Z\",\"i-086f957ee\",
\"Rightsize\",
\"Rightsize\",
\"Rightsize\""`

So not entirely sure how to deal with the array inside the "recommendations" section in jq, I think it might be called unflattening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That didn't overly work for me actually it omitted all the data in the previous array - but thanks!

I ended up with the following, granted it doesn't put the Rightsize details on a seperate line but it will have to do:

jq -r '.result[] | [.service,.name,.resourceIdentifier,.accountName,.vendorAccountId,.availabilityZone,.region,.effectiveHourly,.totalSpend,.idle,.lastSeen,.volumeType,.state,.volumeSize,.iops,.throughput,.lastAttachedTime,.lastAttachedId,.recommendations[][]] |@csv' ./myfile.json

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
jq '.result[] | [ flatten[] | try(.action) // . ] | @csv' file
"\"ebsvolume\",\"gtest\",\"vol-999999999999\",\"g-test-acct\",\"12345678912\",\"ap-southeast-2c\",\"ap-southeast-2\",998.56,167.7,0,\"2018-08-16T22:00:00Z\",\"io1\",\"in-use\",180,2000,500,\"2018-08-08T22:00:00Z\",\"i-086f957ee\",\"Rightsize\",\"Rightsize\",\"Rightsize\""
```

`flatten` does what it says.

`try` tests if `.action` is neither `null` nor `false`. If so, it emits its value, otherwise `jq` emits the other value (operator `//`).

The filtered values are put into an array in order to get them converted with the `@csv` operator.